# Typescript , what's the best approach for declaring a nested object with different types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have this JS object and I want to port it to Typescript:

```
var items = [{
      style: 'activity-8',
      color: '#a32c62',
      id:    8,
      done : false,
      label : {
        short :'999 m',
        long  :'walk 999m',
        statstime  :'yesterday'
      },
      val : {
        today : {
          target   : { 
            raw : 0,
            display :"11"
          },
          achieved : {
            raw : 0,
            display :"22"
          }
        },
        yesterday : {
          target   : {
            raw : 0,
            display :"33"
          },
          achieved : {
            raw : 0,
            display :"44"
          }
        }
      }
    },{
      style: 'activity-7',
      color: '#ec575d',
      id:    7,
      done : true,
      label : {
        short :'walk 555m',
        long  :'walk 555m',
        statstime  :'yesterday'
      },
      val : {
        today : {
          target   : { 
            raw : 0,
            display :"0"
          },
          achieved : {
            raw : 0,
            display :"0"
          }
        },
        yesterday : {
          target   : {
            raw : 0,
            display :"0"
          },
          achieved : {
            raw : 0,
            display :"0"
          }
        }
      }
    }];
```

what's the best approach to declare this object type? shall I write down the types for every field? Or create a custom type? any other suggestions?

Comment: `interface per type` should be good enough

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if it's the "best" way but I will give you example of my way of doing this.

I will try to explain my general rule not only for nested objects:

For all the properties that are base type (string, number, boolean or some Array of something) you can leave them like this, but for every other complex property/nested object that from now on I will call 'Complex property' (because it makes more sense to me) you make an Interface that will be the type of the property.

Example: In your case the `val` property is a 'complex' property so let's split it, starting bottom to top.

The smallest complex property in the val property is `target`, so you make an interface called Target (or ITarget it's not exactly a convention to do that in ts) Target will be something like:

```
interface Target {
  raw: number,
  display: string
}
```

You do the same thing for the `achieved` 'complex' property.

Now you can go one level up. `Today` property is also a 'complex' one so it has to have a type that probably is going to be some type of interface. Thanks to our previous work that interface will look like:

```
interface Day {
  target: Target,
  achieved: Achieved
}
```

You are probably wondering why the interface is called Day and not Today, well the reason is that you have to find out what is the type of the `yesterday` 'complex' property. As you can see you can see it is the same type as the `today` property because it has the same properties inside.

So finally the `val` property that was our goal will have it's own interface that will be something like:

```
interface Val {
  today: Day,
  yesterday: Day
}
```

Next you do the same thing for every other 'complex' property.

Now you can use those in your main object which probably will be a class and its properties' types will be those interfaces.

Don't forget that the interface in ts(and not only) is just a 'helping' tool that only helps to organize your code design. Every interface most of the time should has to have a class that implements that interface. And those are the classes that you will use to actually set some values to those properties.

**UPDATE (4 years later):**

Now when I have more experience with typescript I will still use the same strategy but I'd use the `type` and not `interface` to do the pretty much the same job. The interfaces (for me) should be used only if you intend to have a class that would implement them.

Comment: Interfaces in TypeScript don't have to have classes implementing them. They can be used just for organizing the code and strict typing. In your example you can normally set some value like: 
`var target = <Target>{raw: 5, display: "somestring"}` (where `Target` is just interface). And then:
`var day = <Day>{target: target}`

Comment: I agree with that correction. Even though in that case I think you still are making something like "anonymous" class that implements that interface.

Comment: when we come from object oriented languages like Java, we use interface for specific purposes like declaring some methods that classes can implement. But, in type script it is used both organising code as well as organising behaviour.
If just type can help us organise and if we don't need to implement it, may be we should prefer only types.
If we are modelling a behaviour like flyable that both bird and drone can use that should be interface. This is how it is done in languages like Java. I prefer this approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to extract subtypes (nested fields as separate definitions) because they are used only in that one place, then you can define Interface as follows (code from head)

```ts
interface MyItem {
  style: string,
    color: string,
    id: number,
    done: boolean,
    label: {
      short: string,
      long: string,
      statstime: string,
    },
    val: {
      today: {
        target: {
          raw: number,
          display: string
        },
        achieved: {
          raw: number,
          display: string,
        }
      },
      yesterday: {
        target: {
          raw: number,
          display: string,
        },
        achieved: {
          raw: number,
          display: string,
        }
      }
    }
};


// and map your not-typed items table (eg readed from API) to typed
let typedItem: MyItem[] = items.map(item => new MyItem(item));
```

And use is like this

```js
let items: MyItem[] = [{
  style: 'activity-8',
  color: '#a32c62',
  id: 8,
  done: false,
  label: {
    short: '999 m',
    long: 'walk 999m',
    statstime: 'yesterday'
  },
  val: {
    today: {
      target: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "11"
      },
      achieved: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "22"
      }
    },
    yesterday: {
      target: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "33"
      },
      achieved: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "44"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  style: 'activity-7',
  color: '#ec575d',
  id: 7,
  done: true,
  label: {
    short: 'walk 555m',
    long: 'walk 555m',
    statstime: 'yesterday'
  },
  val: {
    today: {
      target: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "0"
      },
      achieved: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "0"
      }
    },
    yesterday: {
      target: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "0"
      },
      achieved: {
        raw: 0,
        display: "0"
      }
    }
  }
}];
```

Here is working [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=100&ssc=8&pln=36&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CSkC2yDeAsAFDLIDOY6ANhAFwVhSgDmANCWQgPbXdQNKzEO07JgAEwYgArjgBG0DqWQTuIesnndeEOCGVlqcRdQZEVZcgAt+YQU1aGyyPiIfDRlxnDCVgOJpCTmIAvs4AbnBmBGJkYNwScOjI5nEuGWBwUCwQYC7myOkZGVBwAO6pyLIKSsUlZBLA5AAOxikerPUZ4d0uiNbAEBEQElUWDQ1lldJyilDOky5Nre1VwSKLk6F9vd4Z6BCU0EkdsfslWTl5BedLpRVVNfNbSyttyeuOm31ke-fIAZDEZjNIXKaPWa1Ba-ZbND5nDZeAE7cEuVF-EihADcJDxxCiUHEuHIDAw2AgOAA2gBdZAAXmQVImJUoNE0AHJEGBgBFgFQALQADg5r2QPD4AmQHIAxHAAMwAJgQADZFaL6pIGC4hWK1BoqvBqOQIGLjKZxn0bHZUhyAJwO5A4DVotwsMh0DnlaIAa2QDrtzrFViyfh5gQ9HMOxygpw59X+JSi1EtaISp1TAKuuXyHoIRTRDxmyAADMGSu81nQAEQARlr1dhiaWQOGo0zAOQ0yqZdhjXhVerisVjcLyAx23L0cgsc+YKz2RztxZAO7DF7Y-7qzn1fl8tHKPLZFbII7q8hpaPcO3HWrABY7wf7hOGi-0elwiuXGzaAwuQgeT5QUAHYXQaCV+D-GUIAQABWYDYIkMCSi1DJgL1dQUAYJgZFNepzQgFN50ma0oHyT1vWoP1YJooM+jdSNKOo2jkIaShfH8CNbWnE5knjC5mxcZMz0uRI5zue5sxuPN8ALTsuwvDd5MrHcSyfJZBIaE922I89iyUzsVNvNSm12KcjhnDNdMmKTcxEpY10vPtVAHVT1MnWFtNBCS9J7K8twRVJqxMsc3x6BMPxpXFiCAA)

Comment: Isn't `if(item) Object.assign(this, item)` a bit dangerous in a way that it might shallow copy the object, leading to sharing object references between several instances of the class?

Comment: @chnging yes - currently I dropp class-es and use Intefraces - so I update answer